# Is it possible to remap/change the pins of an IC?

Tags: microcontroller, ethernet, pins, pinout, remappable-pins

I was wondering if it would be possible to change the a pin of a microcontroller to another pin. Does it depend on the chip or is it generally (im)possible? Specifically, I'm interested in Ethernet Chips (e.g. DP83848 or lan8720) and changing the rx to the tx pin and vice versa.
In case it is possible can it be done via software or do you need direct access to the hardware?
Datasheets of the chips:

DP83848 http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1668041.pdf

LAN8720 https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/SMSC/LAN8720.pdf

Comment: If the datasheet doesn't say it can be done, it can't.

Comment: You might make an adapter board.  The adapter has the pin-out you want, and has traces to connect the chip's pins to your desired layout.  Probably just easier to properly route the pins on your board, though.

Comment: In microcontrollers, you can sometimes reprogram the micro to substitute pins (for GPIO. You usually can't for more specialized pins ... like Ethernet interfaces). And in a special purpose chip like an Ethernet controller, you certainly can't unless the datasheet explicitly tells you how - as Matt says.

Comment: Don't most Ethernet chips now a days support auto detect between tx and rx in case you hook it up wrong or want to connect peer to peer?  You should check your datasheet in that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about the pins toward the Ethernet wire, those two Ethernet chips have an "autoreverse" function built-in, that's what ["Auto-MDIX"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium-dependent_interface#Auto_MDI-X) means, i.e. detects if the chip at the other end has Tx/Rx reversed and reconfigures itself automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot. For my intended application I strictly require unidirectional communication (Tx Device 1 --> Rx Device 2). It has to be physically impossible for data to go in the opposite direction. So I actually do not want this feature. According to the datasheet of the LAN8720 chip Auto-MDIX can be disabled by a Special control register. Is direct access to the hardware required in order to access the register or can this be done via software (e.g. via some kind of flashing)?

Comment: The DP83848 chip has a similar register, so the same question arises. But this chip also has an extra pin for this feature (MDIX_EN).  Is connecting a resistor to the pin sufficient to deactivate this feature or could it still be reenabled by changing the register? Assuming the feature is disabled or not existent like on [this](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/39662a.pdf) chip, what happens physically if device 2 wants to send data back? Is it somehow blocked in the chip? If so, how?

Comment: @abiss: These devices can still send and received data to each other even if you disable Auto-MDIX... but only if you use the correct cable then. The goal of this Auto-MDIX function is solely to allow you to use any cable (crossover or not). If you use the wrong cable and Auto-MDIX is disabled you can neither send nor receive. For what you want to do, the Ethernet level isn't the way to do it. You may want ask a separate question about that, [clearly stating](http://bit.ly/1BAmifZ) your intended purpose. (Sorry for the late reply, the SE notification system apparently breaks down sometimes.)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to move the pin assignments of an IC chip around. To achieve this you will need to have access to the design files for the IC chip and all of the computer tools used to support that design. It will also be quite helpful to be familiar with the process technology used to build the chip and the packaging technology used to encapsulate the chip and it's lead frame assembly.

There are several possibilities here....

1) If the IC is one that is mounted to a lead frame and the pins to be swapped are conveniently located it may be possible to swap which pads of the chip are wire bonded out to which leads of the lead frame. This scheme requires access to raw IC chip die and careful study of its pad layout to see if swapping in this manner is feasible.

2) If the IC is one that is made with the IC die mounted on a thin package PC board with SMT pads on the bottom it may be possible to re-design that PC board package to adjust which IC pads go to which SMT pad.

3) The deeper design change method will involve changing the IC chip layout design itself. You would be relocating parts of the chip circuits so that the pads in the chip can be organized to come to the periphery of the chip in the desired order. It is not possible to estimate the degree of difficulty in doing this unless the actual circuit design requirements are known. On some ICs there may be metalization routing that can be moved around with ease. On other ICs the circuit functions them selves may need to be moved to allow pads to be relocated.

In any case once you have the strategy worked out you would re-fabricate the chip or package design to build the parts required for your design. I would highly recommend that you also change the part number that gets marked on the outside of the package so these modified parts can be distinguished from the standard parts. One idea would be to append your initials to the end of the standard part number.

Comment: For 3) at least, and maybe for 2), you probably also  need permission from the chip designer, because "mask works" are protected by copyright.

Comment: @ThePhoton - If you are the one down voting this answer for the reasons you stated then please reconsider that I said at the outset of the answer that to move I/Os around via design changes the person doing so needed access to all design files and tools used for the chip design. There is no way that should be construed as a statement that this information should be acquired through theft of IP.

Comment: Thank you, Michael. So in the cases you described it seems there is always direct access to the hardware required. Do you know any integrated circuits* where this is also possible via software/firmware/drivers/whatever? Could you also please take a look a my comments/questions under Respawned Fluffs answer.       * I'm still mostly interested in the ethernet chips, though this is maybe to specialized.